# Extension functions and 'help'

Tags: python, cpython

When I call

```
help(Mod.Cls.f)
```

(Mod is a C extension module), I get the output

```
Help on method_descriptor:

f(...)
    doc_string
```

What do I need to do so that the help output is of the form

```
Help on method f in module Mod:

f(x, y, z)
    doc_string
```

like it is for random.Random.shuffle, for example?

My PyMethodDef entry is currently:

```
{ "f", f, METH_VARARGS, "doc_string" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The inspect module, which is what 'pydoc' and 'help()' use, has no way of figuring out what the exact signature of a C function is. The best you can do is what the builtin functions do: include the signature in the first line of the docstring:

```
>>> help(range)
Help on built-in function range in module __builtin__:

range(...)
    range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers

...
```

The reason random.shuffle's docstring looks "correct" is that it isn't a C function. It's a function written in Python.

Comment: Thanks, but why does it say method_descriptor rather than the name of the method and module?

Comment: Because that's what Python thinks the object is -- because that's what it is. See 'help(list.append)' and you'll see the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see ... help(list.sort) does exactly the same. If it's good enough for list.sort, it's good enough for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thomas's answer is right on, of course.

I would simply add that many C extension modules have a Python "wrapper" around them so that they can support standard function signatures and other dynamic-language features (such as the descriptor protocol).